# Browser compatibility between IE6 and IE7

Tags: html, ajax, internet-explorer-6, internet-explorer-7, cross-browser

I'm developing a project in which I need to change the language according to the flag I click using AJAX. It's working fine in IE7 but it shows an error when I run it in IE6.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
    <script language="javascript">   
google.load("language", "1"); 

function fnTrans(strTransText,strTransField, strTransFLang, strTransTLang)
{
    google.language.translate(strTransText, strTransFLang, strTransTLang, function(result) {
      var strcontainer = document.getElementById(strTransField);
      strcontainer.innerHTML = result.translation ;  
      });
}

function initialize(strToTxtBox, strFromTxtBox) {
    var x = window.location.toString();
    var strLang = x.substring(x.indexOf("=")+1);
    if((x.indexOf("="))==-1) return;
    strFLang = strLang.substring(0,2)
    strTLang = strLang.substring(strLang.indexOf("-")+1);
    var strText = document.getElementById(strFromTxtBox).innerHTML;

    if(strFLang != 'en')
        fnTrans(strText,strFromTxtBox, 'en',strFLang)

    fnTrans(strText,strToTxtBox, strFLang,strTLang) 
}

function fnhi()
{
    var label=document.getElementsByTagName("label");
    var count=label.length;
    var x = window.location.toString();
    var strLang = x.substring(x.indexOf("=")+1);
    if((x.indexOf("="))==-1)
         return;
    for(var i=0;i<count;i++)
          {
        initialize(label[i].id,label[i].id);
    }
document.getElementById("curlang").value=strTLang;
}

function fnClick(lang)
{
    if(lang=="") return;
    var curlang=document.getElementById("curlang").value;
    if(lang==curlang) return;
    window.location='language.php?strLang=' + curlang+'-'+lang;
}

    </script>
    </head>
    <body onload="fnhi()">
    <input type="hidden" id="curlang" value="en" size="3">
    <img src= "langauage.gif" use ="#map">
    <map name="Map">
        <area shape="rect" alt="Arabic" value="ar" coords="36,6,62,19" href="#" onclick="fnClick(this.value);">
        <area shape="rect" alt="Chinese" value="zh" coords="66,6,90,20" href="#" onclick="fnClick(this.value);">
        <area shape="rect" alt="German" value="de" coords="95,6,121,21" href="#" onclick="fnClick(this.value);">
    </map>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: "it show error when i run it in IE6". What error are you seeing in IE6?

Comment: @Paul, this is IE6.  Whatever the error is it won't be informative ;-)

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear what is the question.
Therefore I am guessing.
If you want to do something in javascript browser dependant then 
you can ask from which browser the request have been sent.

```
<html>
<body>

<script type="text/javascript">
var browser=navigator.appName;
var b_version=navigator.appVersion;
var version=parseFloat(b_version);

document.write("Browser name: "+ browser);
document.write("<br />");
document.write("Browser version: "+ version);
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Then adding "if" statements you can "customize" the behaviour dependent the browser.
Anyway *I DO NOT ADVICE TO DO THIS* because you have to maintain your code for 
all the browsers. Also you have to test different browsers and browser versions.

A possible solution is tu use some javascript libraries which are crossbrowser
like GWT from Google.

Luis

Answer (score 0):

You should try http://code.google.com/p/jquery-translate/ instead!